# Circle and right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I'm considering $A=(-1,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and the unit circle of center $O=(0,0)$. The dot $K=(x,y)$ is on the circle. My aim is to prove that $ABK$ is a right triangle. 
Since $AB=2KO$, I have 
$$ AB^2=4x^2+4y^2.$$
Moreover, $BK^2=(x-1)^2+y^2$ and $AK^2=(x+1)^2+y^2$. 
Hence, $BK^2+AK^2=2x^2+2y^2+2$. 
How can I prove **simply** , without using circle equation ect, that $$ AB^2=AK^2+KB^2\quad ?$$
Did I miss an information?

Comment: (i) What is $x^2+y^2$? (ii) What do you get if you expand your expressions for $BK^2$ and $AK^2$ and add them?

Comment: By the way, I have edited your question to say that the circle has radius $1$. Without this information, it is not true that $ABK$ must be a right triangle.

Comment: I get $2x^2+2y^2+2$ which gives me the equation of the unit circle. But that's not what I want to prove.

Comment: You mean $AKB$, not $ABK$. https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Outline/Geometry/AngleOnDiameter.shtml https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Inscribed_angles_where_one_chord_is_a_diameter

Comment: @EthanBolker: No, the question says right _triangle_, not right angle.

Comment: @J.Darmody: So now substitute your answer to my question (i) into your expression for $AK^2+KB^2$.

Comment: It's a right triangle whose right angle is at $K$. That means you want to prove the angle at $K$ is right.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Yes. $ABK$ is a right triangle if any of its three angles is a right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Relate what you have found so far to the numbers that were given. Since $AB$ is a diameter from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ it has length $2$. Combining this with your expression for $AB$, or by simply noting that $K$ is a point on the unit circle, we have $x^2+y^2=1\Rightarrow y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Then what are the sizes of $AK^2$ and $BK^2$?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have multiple equations with lots of variables ($x^2+xy^2+\ldots$), try to solve each one in terms of one variable ($y=x+\ldots$). This allows you to substitute each equation into each other, so it cuts down the number of variables and makes the problem easier to solve.

Comment: This rule of thumb doesn't apply to the problem at hand: it is much simpler to work with the expression $x^2+y^2$ than to eliminate $x$ or $y$.

Comment: I was aiding the OP in tying together the numerous equations they had, so the rule of thumb applied to the situation they had arrived at. It may well have been simpler to simply recognise that $2x^2+2y^2+2=2(x^2+y^2)+2$ but given that they did not seem to see that, I was giving them another route.

Answer (score 0):

I get
$$AB=(2,0),AK=(x+1,y),BK=(x-1,y)$$ So $$4=(x+1)^2+y^2+(x-1)^2+y^2$$ This is $$4=2x^2+2y^2+2$$ Since we have the unit circle $$x^2+y^2=1$$ we get $$4=2+2$$. That is true.

Comment: I was trying to get the OP to work this out on their own. Oh well.

Comment: No, I don't want the equation of the unit circle. I want to find a simple proof that $ AB^2=BK^2+KA^2$ ...

Comment: @J.Darmody: It seems to me that we are explaining things to you, and you are simply determined not to understand our explanations.